# Auto-Generate Emails using SQL

Tags: sql-server

I come from a programming background, and i'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around SQL's conditionals. 
I'm looking to auto-generate emails when two criteria are met in my sql table.

If the value in column NextTestDate is not null AND today's date is equivalent to the next test date + 30 days  THEN generate an email.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.datmaintest
if NextTestDate is NOT NULL
AND DATEADD(day,30,DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())) = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(day, 0, NextTest), 0) then

BEGIN               
use msdb
    GO
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='ControllerDB',
    @recipients='test@test.com',
    @subject='ITS ALIVE!',
    @body='Time to grab lunch'
END
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL server? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: For clarification NextTestDate and GETDATE both return a date and time value. The extra code around my second conditional ensures that the time does not interfere with my date comparison

Comment: @JohnConde SQL server

Comment: Are you asking how to set up `Database Mail`?  (Or is that part working already?)

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do here but your condition is not going to work like that. I suspect you just want to use an EXISTS. Not sure what the point of all the date math is on NextTestDate since it will effectively return the same value.

Comment: @DMason That part is working already

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not looking for guidance on the date math. I'm just trying to figure out how to submit an email when my two criteria are met.

Comment: Well your date math seems very strange to me. I realize it isn't in your question but it is all related.

Comment: What "event" is supposed to occur to cause your code to run?  Do you want your code to "run" on the entire table?  One row?  Two or more rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think that you are looking for something like this.

```
IF EXISTS(
    select *
    FROM dbo.datmaintest
    where DATEADD(day, 30, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())) = NextTestDate
)

    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='ControllerDB'
        , @recipients = 'test@test.com'
        , @subject = 'ITS ALIVE!'
        , @body = 'Time to grab lunch'
```

Comment: Sean, thank you for your suggestion. I was able to get my query to work with a few slight modification on your answer. I do have one additional question, is there a way to include the ID number of each of the results in the generated email? (Assuming the column name is ID)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started (I'm assuming that in the date logic portion, you meant to type 'NextTestDate' instead of 'NextTest'):

```
DECLARE @NextTestDate DATETIME
SET @NextTestDate = (SELECT TOP 1 NextTestDate FROM dbo.datmaintest)

--If the value is not null and today is equal to the value of 'next test date' + 30 days:

IF @NextTestDate IS NOT NULL 
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, @NextTestDate, GETDATE()) = 30

    BEGIN               
    use msdb
        GO
        EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='ControllerDB',
        @recipients='test@test.com',
        @subject='ITS ALIVE!',
        @body='Time to grab lunch'
    END
```

Basically, declare a variable and set it to the value from the database you want to check.  Then, perform your check and if it is true, begin the email sending (and close it out with an END)

Comment: Thank you for your answer koppinjo. This also seems to be a viable solution